# Who wants vs Who does want

Tags: questions

I watched a tv show, a quiz program, the name of the program is "Who wants to be a millionaire". Well I don't want to be a millionare, at least not right now, but the title always makes me curious somehow, I thought the correct sentence would be "Who does want to be". What are their differences then ?

Comment: When "who" works as a subject and interrogative pronoun at the *same time*, you don't use an auxiliary verb "do" to make an interrogative sentence.

Comment: The title is taken from a [song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire%3F_(song)) by Cole Porter. Once you've heard lots of people sing it, you might be inclined to ask "Well, who *does* want to be a millionaire, then?"

Comment: This question has been asked, and answered, [many times before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/323?lq=1). Even though it's way too basic for this site. If you can't tell the difference between the two, we recommend that you take your questions to [our sister site for learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Rathony, exactly what I mean, like this, 'Who IS your name?", that 'IS'. While 'Who DOES want', that 'DOES' thanks.

Comment: As RegDwight suggested, you can visit the sister site and post your question or look up the grammar book for yourself.

Comment: @Rathony, I just found an answer based on your comment, you're right! We  don't normally use 'Who/What etc', along with do/does. The do/does transforms the question to be an emphatic question, Thank you so much!!